# Tracking GPS points and finding their nearest neighbours?

Tags: android, mysql, algorithm, gps, nearest-neighbor

I have a list of 1 million (slowly) moving points on the globe (stored as latitude and longitude). Every now and then, each point requests a list of the 100 nearest other points (with a configurable max range, if that helps).

Unfortunately, `SELECT * SORT BY compute_geodetic_distance() LIMIT 100` is too slow to be done by each point over and over again. So my question: how should I handle this efficiently? Are there better algorithms/datastructures/... known for this? Or is this the only way and should I look into distributing server load?

(Note: this is for an Android app and the points are users, so in case I'm missing an android-specific solution, feel free to say so!)

Comment: @eggyal, no ist an 2d indexing problem, to reduce one million to some hundred operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your task geo spatial databases have been invented.
There is Oracle Spatial (expensive)  and PostGres (free).
These databases store your millions points in a geographical index, a quad tree (Oracle). 
Such a query needs nearly no time.

Some people, like me prefer to leave the database away and build up the quadtree themselfs.

The operations search and insert are easy to implement. Update/delete can be more complex.(Cheapest related to implementation effort, is to build up a new quadtree evry minute)

Using a quadtree you can perform hundreds or thousansds of such nearest 100 points within a second.

Comment: @eggyal  because it is a sortby. the reduction from one million to a few must be done before, e.g in a where clausel using a spatial extesion.

Comment: I see that the comment mentioning that MySQL also has spatial extensions, has vanished. So I'm posting this again, as I find it valuable information.

Comment: Would you mind to explain how I can do "thousands of such nearest 100 points within a second"? For given point `curr` I now select the nearest 100 points by `SELECT user_id, GLENGTH(LINESTRINGFROMWKB(LINESTRING(ASBINARY(curr),ASBINARY(pt)))) AS distance ORDER BY distance LIMIT 100`, but this is actually quite slow. Perhaps things would be faster if I could add a WHERE-clause, but I see no way to determine in advance whether the nearest 100 points will be within a 5 km range, or a 5000 km range.

Comment: The question is do you really want the  100 nearest points, even if only 50 points are within 100km? (so where distance < x). If you have not found enough you could duplicate the distance x in the where clause. For your exact question, it would be better to load the whole coordinates in main memory and use your own quad tree. In that case you know when to stop.

Comment: I'm afraid 100km radius will for often only yield 1-2 points in rural areas. And 1000km radius may potentially include half the userbase. About building my own tree in memory: can this be done in PHP somehow? And if not, how can I make it interact with the rest of my application, which is written in PHP/MySQL on the server side?

Comment: Alternatively, is there a way to do a binary search to find the right radius? Start with COUNT() for 100km, and depending on the result go to 50 or 200 km? Then count again and goto 25 or 75, or 150 or 400? Or is the complexity of COUNT() not better than that of SELECT in these quad trees? (i.e. is it a problem to do a COUNT() which returns 500000?)

Comment: Here in So is a good answer which is usefuell for many application. The trick is to calculate from given radius the maxLatitude, minLatitude, maxLongitude and minLongitude, and use that in the where clausel. This will reduce your search. Then with that you can do a binary search as you told.

Answer (score 0):

Architecturally I would arrange for each "point" to phone home to a server with their location when it changes more than a certain amount. On the server you can do the heavy lifting of calculating the distance between the point that moved and each of the other points, and for each of the other points updating their list of the 100 closest points if required. You can then push changes to a point's closest 100 list as they happen (trivial if you are using App Engine, Android push is supported).

This reduces the amount of work involved to an absolute minimum:

- Only report a location change when a point moves far enough
- Only recalculate distances when a report is received
- Don't rebuild the closest 100 list for a point every time, build the list once, then work out if a point that has moved is going to be added or removed from every other point's list.
- Only notify a point of changes to its top 100 list to preserve bandwidth.

There are algorithms that you can use to make this super-efficient, and the problem has a fork/join feel to it as well, allowing you to throw horsepower at the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to divide the earth into zones and then use an interior point algorithm to figure out what zones the phone is in. Each possible subset of zones will uniquely determine the 100 closest nodes to a fair approximation. You can get an exact set of 100 nodes by checking distance one by one against the candidate nodes, which (once again) are determined by the subset of zones.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of r-tree or a quadtree, I.e spatial index  you can also use a quadkey and a monster curve. This curve reduce the dimension and completetly fills the space. You can download my php class hilbert curve from phpclasses.org. You can use a simple varchar column for the quadkey and search the levels from left to right. A good explanation is from Microsoft Bing maps quadkey website.